# Django cms: {% url %} tag is not loading under static_placeholders [ django-cms version : 3.5.2 ]

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-cms

**Use-case:**
 The requirement is to push my site's footer to static-placeholders.

**Example:**

```
<footer id="DarkFooter">
    <p>disclaimer txt<p>
    <!-- some links of the site in list --!>
    <ul>
        <li class="footer-item" id="ContactFooter"><a href="{% url 'app1:contact' %}">Contact</a></li>
```

Now I want the contents to be in static placeholder.
Changed the above footer as  -

```
{% load cms_tags %}
<footer id="DarkFooter">
    {% static_placeholder 'footerv1' %}
</footer>
```

**Issue:**
After changing to static_placeholders the url tags are not loaded.The contact us link is loading with 
`https://localhost/page1/%7B%%20url%20'app1:contact'%20%%7D`

( here `app1:contact` was my argument to url tag)

Comment: how did you add the text to the static placeholder? text plugin?

Comment: @Paulo - Yes , used text plugin ( added under source tab )

Comment: If you've put django template tags in the text editor then that's not valid. The contents of that aren't passed through the template rendering parts of the system. If you've got something in the ckeditor it can just contain HTML elements. The CMS link plugin allows for linking to CMS pages though which can be included within text plugins.

Comment: @markwalker_  - Thanks for the reply. Is there any django-cms plugin that is available so that I can access the urls.py URLs ( pages that are not in CMS ) ?Guess there can be use-cases where cms pages need to redirect to some other page which is outside of CMS.

Comment: @nkkrishnak not that I know of. You could obviously write a plugin which could do it. But if you're in a text plugin, you don't have dynamic data so the usual way to do it would be hard-code the URLs because you'll know what they are.